# It has just one issue that it plays multiple songs if selected, rest everything works fine

Tags: android, performance, optimization

the issue is, I have checked whether media player is null or not, if not I have applied release() method but still when I select another song to play, it plays new song but it doesn't stop the previous one. While playing next or previous on click also works fine. so why it is not detecting that mediaplayer is playing.
here is java code.

```
public class Musicplay extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button play,next,previous;
    TextView songmar;
    SeekBar seekBar;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    int position,idr;
    Handler handler=new Handler();
    Handler vindler=new Handler();
    Uri uri;
    int max;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.playdisplay);

        Intent i=getIntent();
        position=i.getIntExtra("position",0);
        play=findViewById(R.id.pause);
        next=findViewById(R.id.next);
        previous=findViewById(R.id.previous);
        songmar=findViewById(R.id.songnamemar);
        songmar.setSelected(true);
        songmar.setText(Musiclist.songname.get(position));
        seekBar=findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

        if(mediaPlayer==null)
        {
            Log.d("null","null");
        }
        else {
            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();
            }
            else {
                mediaPlayer.release();
            }
        }


        uri=Uri.parse(String.valueOf(new File(Musiclist.songpath.get(position))));
        mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(Musicplay.this,uri);
        seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
        mediaPlayer.start();
        max=mediaPlayer.getDuration();
        play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
        Thread thread=new Thread(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                super.run();



                int currentposition=0;
                while (currentposition<max)
                {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    currentposition=mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                    seekBar.setProgress(currentposition);


                }



            }


        };
        thread.start();
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                mediaPlayer.seekTo(seekBar.getProgress());
            }
        });

        next.setOnClickListener(Musicplay.this);
        play.setOnClickListener(Musicplay.this);
        previous.setOnClickListener(Musicplay.this);


        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                mp.stop();
                mp.reset();


                if(position<(Musiclist.songname.size()-1)){
                    position=position +1;
                }
                else
                {
                    position=0;
                }
                uri = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(new File(Musiclist.songpath.get(position))));
                try {
                    mp.setDataSource(Musicplay.this,uri);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                songmar.setText(Musiclist.songname.get(position));
                songmar.setSelected(true);

                try {
                    mp.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }


        });
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.start();
                seekBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());
                max=mp.getDuration();
                Log.d("seekvalue",String.valueOf(max));
            }
        });




    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        idr=v.getId();

        Thread thread2=new Thread(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                super.run();

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        switch (idr){
                            case R.id.pause:
                                if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                                    play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_play);

                                }
                                else {
                                    play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                                    mediaPlayer.start();
                                }
                                break;
                            case R.id.next:
                                mediaPlayer.stop();
                                mediaPlayer.reset();
                                if(position<(Musiclist.songname.size()-1)){
                                    position=position +1;
                                    Uri uri=Uri.parse(String.valueOf(new File(Musiclist.songpath.get(position))));
                                    try {
                                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(Musicplay.this,uri);
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    int a=0;
                                    for(int i=0;i<150;i++)
                                    {
                                        a=a+1;
                                    }
                                    try {
                                        mediaPlayer.prepare();
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                                    songmar.setText(Musiclist.songname.get(position));
                                    songmar.setSelected(true);
                                }
                                else {
                                    position=0;
                                    Uri uri=Uri.parse(String.valueOf(new File(Musiclist.songpath.get(position))));
                                    try {
                                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(Musicplay.this,uri);
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    int a=0;
                                    for(int i=0;i<150;i++)
                                    {
                                        a=a+1;
                                    }
                                    try {
                                        mediaPlayer.prepare();
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                                    songmar.setText(Musiclist.songname.get(position));
                                    songmar.setSelected(true);
                                }
                                

                                break;
                            case R.id.previous:
                                mediaPlayer.stop();
                                mediaPlayer.reset();
                                if(position>0){
                                    position=position-1;
                                    Uri uri=Uri.parse(String.valueOf(new File(Musiclist.songpath.get(position))));
                                    try {
                                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(Musicplay.this,uri);
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    int a=0;
                                    for(int i=0;i<150;i++)
                                    {
                                        a=a+1;
                                    }
                                    try {
                                        mediaPlayer.prepare();
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                                    songmar.setText(Musiclist.songname.get(position));
                                    songmar.setSelected(true);
                                }
                                else {
                                    position=Musiclist.songname.size()-1;
                                    Uri uri=Uri.parse(String.valueOf(new File(Musiclist.songpath.get(position))));
                                    try {
                                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(Musicplay.this,uri);
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    int a=0;
                                    for(int i=0;i<150;i++)
                                    {
                                        a=a+1;
                                    }
                                    try {
                                        mediaPlayer.prepare();
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                                    songmar.setText(Musiclist.songname.get(position));
                                    songmar.setSelected(true);
                                }
                                break;
                        }


                    }
                });




            }
        };

        thread2.start();






    }

   
}
```

so do suggest reason why this error is taking place, and it is playing two or multiple song simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you have to do is, just declare mediaplayer variable public static and when you start activity to play song just check for media player is null or not and then release it